# How to use SQL Server datetime type in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, Java 7 and Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server.

Once I have a ResultSet named rs what's the simplest method to get a "Date and Time" type from a datetime column from which I can extract day, month, year, hour, minute and second?

With other types I can simply use rs.getString("column name") rs.getInt("column name") etc. methods but getDate return a Date type and getHour() etc. are marked as deprecated in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use rs.getDate("column name")

It will return a type [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), this extends the class [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) from there you can get all the date stuff you need.

You mentioned that the .getHour() getDay() ect. are depreciated, well java date packages are really dumb and made poorly. It is now using the Calendar class, use the following

```
Date d = rs.getDate("date_column");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d.getTime());
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

More calendar examples at [java-forms.org](http://www.java-forums.org/java-tip/3289-how-use-calendar-class.html)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion about Calendar type I found and used the method

    Date java.sql.ResultSet.getDate(String columnLabel, Calendar cal) throws SQLException

that directly stores in cal parameter all information without explicitly using set method (it probably does exactly geTime() and setTime() of your code). Then I neglected Date returned and retrieved correctly from cal: day of month, month, year, hour of day, minute and second.

Comment: @Ufo.rob What you are doing is inviting inexplicable bugs. Read the javadoc of resultSet.getDate(column, calendar) properly - the provided calendar is *used* by the method to retrieve time zone information. There is *absolutely no guarantee* that the calendar will reflect the date returned (that is an implementation detail and may be different between drivers and versions). Relying on such behavior is dangerous because it can change without notice when you update the driver. Suddenly your code breaks for no apparent reason. The code in the answer is safer, even if it is longer.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong. Then I saw that method doesn't affect cal variable.